# How to add the results of a sql oracle query in a csv file in php?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, csv

I have a php code that I connect to an oracle database and with a request to retrieve the information I want, here is my code :

```
$query = "SELECT ACTIVE_SIZES FROM ADA_ACTIVE_SIZE2_VIEW WHERE ADA_STYLE = 'SCPCL4'";  
$result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);
  
   while($final = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
        
         print_r($final); //Array ( [ACTIVE_SIZES] => XS-S-M-L-XL-2XL )
        
       }
```

Now I'm reading a csv file and I would like to adapt this code to add the results of my queries in a column at the end of the file. I already add two columns at the end of this one, but my query doesn't return anything in the csv file, how can I do please?

```
<?php 
//Modifications on csv file
$delimiter = ";"; 
$csv_data = array();
if (($handle = fopen($nomcsv, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
        //Add two columns at the end
        $data['Pictures Names'] = (!empty($data[4]) ? ($data[7] ?: '') . "_" . $data[4] . '.jpg' : ''); 
        $data['Color-Description'] = (!empty($data[3]) ? (ltrim($data[4], '0') ?: '') . "-" . $data[3] : '');  
        
        //Query
        $query = "SELECT ACTIVE_SIZES FROM ADA_ACTIVE_SIZE2_VIEW WHERE ADA_STYLE = '".$data[4]."'";
        $result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);
        
         while($final = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
        
                $data['Sizes'] = $final;
               var_dump($final); //array(1) { ["ACTIVE_SIZES"]=> string(8) "XS-S-M-L" }array(1) { ["ACTIVE_SIZES"]=> string(8) "XS-S-M-L" }...
            
        }  
        
            $csv_data[] = $data; 
            var_dump($csv_data); //["Pictures Names"]=> string(15) "SCJEG4_1041.jpg" ["Color-Description"]=> string(12) "1041-MUSTARD" ["Sizes"]=> array(1) { ["ACTIVE_SIZES"]=> string(15) "XS-S-M-L-XL-2XL" } } }
             
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

if (($handle = fopen($nomcsv, 'w')) !== FALSE) {
    foreach ($csv_data as $data) {
        fputcsv($handle, $data, $delimiter);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

At the end I have this in my csv file:

[image]

Comment: This is identical post to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64751155/how-to-add-the-result-of-a-sql-oracle-query-in-a-csv-file-in-php Please do not abuse the system

Comment: Do you know what link of your chain is breaking?  I would start by verifying the contents of `$data`.   Then, the value of `$query`.  Then the value of `$final`. Then the value of `$csv_data`.  And so forth...  BTW, your SQL is open to injection; read up on prepared statements.

Comment: With a print_r($final); I have all my information, but you think the problem is the array_push? @TimMorton

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: So far, so good.  Now check `$csv_data`.   Keep going until you find bad data or it fails to do what you expect.

Comment: On the last column of my csv there is just written "array" on each line, what can this be due to ? With a print_r($csv_data) I have well the infos ? @TimMorton

Comment: $data['sizes'] = $final

Comment: I have the same, "array" on each line @Jerson

Comment: I updated my code and I put in comment the end of each line of my csv @Jerson

Comment: I updated with a var_dump as well as one I put what comes out in my csv file, you can watch @Jerson

Comment: ["Pictures Names"]=> string(15) "SCJEG4_1041.jpg" 
["Color-Description"]=> string(12) "1041-MUSTARD"
 ["Sizes"]=> array(1) { ["ACTIVE_SIZES"]=> string(15) "XS-S-M-L-XL-2XL" } } }

Comment: The problem comes from there, how can I convert the last element with the same format?

Comment: With a print_r(array_values($csv_data) i have :  [Sizes] => Array ( [ACTIVE_SIZES] => XS-S-M-L-XL-2XL ) )

Comment: I have this : "bool(false) bool(false) array(1) { ["ACTIVE_SIZES"]=> string(15) "XS-S-M-L-XL-2XL" } array(1) { ["ACTIVE_SIZES"]=> string(15) "XS-S-M-L-XL-2XL" } bool(false) ...". It's normal that he can only find two sizes because I sent only two of them

Comment: going back to the last comment to me, you have found the problem. CSV defines a flat file. But `$final` is an array. You’ll have to either aggregate it or have a separate `$csv_data` line for each size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, only thing is you need to define your ActiveSizes index and push it to the sizes index

```
  $delimiter = ";"; 
  $csv_data = array();
  if (($handle = fopen($nomcsv, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
          //Add two columns at the end
          $data['Pictures Names'] = (!empty($data[4]) ? ($data[7] ?: '') . "_" . $data[4] . '.jpg' : ''); 
          $data['Color-Description'] = (!empty($data[3]) ? (ltrim($data[4], '0') ?: '') . "-" . $data[3] : '');  
          
          //Query
          $query = "SELECT ACTIVE_SIZES FROM ADA_ACTIVE_SIZE2_VIEW WHERE ADA_STYLE = '".$data[4]."'";

          $result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);
          
          while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
          
              $data['Sizes'][] = $row['ACTIVE_SIZES'];
              
          }  
          
          $csv_data[] = $data; 
              
      }
      
      fclose($handle);
  }

  //var_dump($csv_data);

  if (($handle = fopen($nomcsv, 'w')) !== FALSE) {
      foreach ($csv_data as $data) {
          fputcsv($handle, $data, $delimiter);
      }

      fclose($handle);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and explanations, it works perfectly! I just have a problem is that the header of the column is empty, how can I put 'SIZES' as its name?

Comment: just do fputcsv($handle,['first_column'',"second_column" , .... blah blah]) put this before foreach